# correcting delay between two samples

Tags: sampling, delay

I'm sampling two signals with fundamental frequency of 50 Hz. I want to sample them at the same instant, but there's a delay between the first and the second conversion. I don't keep the previous values of the signals in an array, at most I can store 10/20 samples.

I want to correct this delay. I thought of a FIR fractional delay, but i'm not sure is the right way to do it.

Comment: Do you know what the delay is, or do you you need to figure out what the delay is from the 10/20 samples?

Comment: I know the delay and it's always the same.

Comment: Then yes, a FIR fractional delay filter would be very appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are sampling above the Nyquist rate, then an interpolation kernel or equivalent fractional FIR filter on one or both channels (both to match up any non-zero processing delays) might be an appropriate solution.